# What is the negative form of 'eco-friendly'?

Tags: antonyms, negation

> The methodology to treat the infection of XXX mostly use chemical pesticides, which is less effective and **not eco-friendly**, as well as it produces a residue.

Is "not eco-friendly" a negative form?

Comment: Environmentally harmful, environmentally hazardous, bad/hazardous for the environment, detrimental to the environment.. etc.

Comment: Side note:  you must say either, ".... and not eco-friendly, *producing* a residue as well" or create a second independent clause, "...and not eco-friendly; it *produces* a residue as well."  *Leaves* is a better verb than *producing* when residues are concerned.  You might also consider "...as well, as ...'

Comment: A third alternative: "... which is less effective and not eco-friendly as well, as it leaves a residue"  -- that is, a comma after "as well".  **As well** there = moreover, in addition.

Comment: @TRomano: so the phrase "not eco-friendly" can be used?

Comment: Yes it can be used. The alternatives CopperKettle suggested are neutral, objective non-trendy terms.  **Eco-friendly** is something of a commercialism.

Comment: @TRomano: while 'not eco-friendly' is a negative form, is it better to use 'either' instead of 'as well'? or is it just a free choice?

Comment: **Either** would not be correct. You could write: "...chemical pesticides, which are *not only* less effective than [whatever solution you had in mind] *but also* leave a residue hazardous to the environment."

Comment: What about "Toxic," "Polluting," and "not green"?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, technically speaking, *not eco-friendly* is the negative form of *eco-friendly*. This is just like saying that the negative form of *a good man* is *not a good man*. Simple as that. But the closest thing I can think of that can be considered a more interesting negative form for *eco-friendly* is:

> detrimental to the environment

As many people have already pointed out, your original sentence does sound slightly awkward. So, I changed the wording a little bit:

> The most common method used to prevent plant diseases today is use of pesticides which in reality are not even that effective and can actually be very detrimental to the environment. They also leave residual deposits which remain in the ground for years.

Also, check out the suggestions offered by *[CopperKettle](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74406/what-is-the-negative-form-of-eco-friendly#comment142987_74406)* in the comments section.

Answer (score 3):

"eco-unfriendly" would be the opposite of "eco-friendly".

"Not eco-friendly" could mean either "eco-unfriendly" or "eco-neutral".

Comment: All of these words are recent inventions.  Their meanings and connotations still vary, depending on who says them.